# Matplotlib text transparency

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was wondering if it is possible to change the transparency of a text in Matplotlib. `set_alpha` does not function and in the documentation I couldn't find anything relevant. Are there may be any workarounds?

I want to connect it to a pick_event.

***EDIT:***
I was actually trying to change the transparency of a legend-text. Although I tried to solve the issue with `set_alpha`, I have overseen that I was trying to modify the transparency of a list and hence I couldn't succeed. To sum up, as can be seen from answers, the transparency can be modified with `set_alpha`

Comment: You got answers on this question because it was simple and people could guess what you were trying to do.  It is best to include a minimal (not) working example of what you have tried and the full backtrace you got.

Comment: @tcaswell thanks for your comments and remarks. I have edited my question in order to explain what my problem was, what the answers provide etc. I think, now it has become more clear for future readers to understand the question.

Comment: You comment does not make sense.  `leg.texts` is a python list, not an mpl object.  Everything behaves exactly the same and the texts in the legend are just normal `Text` objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set alpha when using `annotate` to add the text to your figure.

Before:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

ax.annotate("TESTING", xy=(.5, .5), xytext=(.5, .5))

plt.show()
```

[image]

After:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

text = ax.annotate("TESTING", xy=(.5, .5), xytext=(.5, .5))

text.set_alpha(.4)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is it also possible to do that after the text is set? When I click onto it, I want it to be transparent...

Comment: I tried to use set_alpha but in my case it didn't work... I am actually trying to change the transparency of a text that belongs to a legend... Apparently, I'm missing something out...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set alpha on the legend text, you should have said so:

```
ax.plot([1,2,3], [4,5,6], label='Null')
leg = ax.legend()

# print dir(leg) # inspection
for _txt in leg.texts:
    _txt.set_alpha(0.3)
```

Side note: Because I can never remember where exactly to find things in the mpl docs, I inspected the legend object. Attribute `texts` sounded useful.

Comment: @T-1000 Read the documentation on `Text` http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text  Do not ask _new_ questions in the comments.  Both of these answers address you original question (including the fact that it is a moving target).  Please accept one of them and open a _new_ question with any additional questions.

Comment: By the way, print `dir(leg)` is very useful! Thanks for that side note